# Get HTML element generated from JavaScript

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this input field generated by JavaScript

```
<input class="postal-code form-text required form-control" autocomplete="postal-code" data-drupal-selector="edit-field-client-address-0-address-postal-code" type="text" id="edit-field-client-address-0-address-postal-code--bwzakXWpxR0" name="field_client_address[0][address][postal_code]" value="" size="10" maxlength="128" required="required" aria-required="true">
```

As you can see every time the id String is different: `id="edit-field-client-address-0-address-postal-code--bwzakXWpxR0"`

What is the proper way to locate this id using Selenium?

Comment: You can give a try with class attribute

Comment: Can you give me example please?

Answer (score 1):

you can try using the following

```
driver.findElement(By.className("postal-code")).sendKeys("your value");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with other locators if the id is dynamic.

**CSS Selector:**

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(input[data-drupal-selector='edit-field-client-address-0-address-postal-code'])).sendKeys("your value");
```

Comment: That won't work because `By.className()` accepts only a single class name and you've passed in 4.

Comment: Agree, haven't noticed the spaces properly and modified now.

Answer (score 0):

There are a LOT of attributes that seem to be unique. Have you tried any of them? Potential CSS selectors

```
input[autocomplete='postal-code']
input[data-drupal-selector='edit-field-client-address-0-address-postal-code']
input[name='field_client_address[0][address][postal_code]']
```

or you can try ID starts with, e.g.

```
input[id^='id="edit-field-client-address-0-address-postal-code--']
```

Answer (score 0):

As the desired element is an `<input>` element so moving next you would either invoke `click()` or `sendKeys()`, so to locate the element you need to use `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.postal-code[id*='address-postal-code'][name^='field_client_address']")));
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='postal-code form-text required form-control' and contains(@id, 'address-postal-code')][starts-with(@name, 'field_client_address')]")));
  ```